Help Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(\pi x)\ln(\Gamma(1-x))dx$
\begin{align}
\mbox{I am evaluating}\ & \int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\pi x\right)\ln\left(\Gamma\left(1 - x\right)\right)\,{\rm d}x
\\ \mbox{and in doing so am trying to find}\ & \int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\pi x\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right){\rm d}x:
\end{align}

Initially I thought of using a simple IBP with $u = \ln\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right)$ and ${\rm d}v = \sin\left(\pi x\right)$ but that leads to the following:
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\pi x\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right){\rm d}x
\\[2mm] = & \
\left.-\frac{1}{\pi}\,\cos\left(\pi x\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right)\right\vert_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ 1} + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos^{2}\left(\pi x\right)}{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{\rm d}x
\end{align}
Both of these objects diverge, but the integral in question converges.
I am not asking how to solve the integral, I can figure out another way.
I am asking why doesn't this yield any reasonable answer ?. Why doesn't IBP work here ?.

Is it something about the integrand
$$
\sin\left(\pi x\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\pi x\right)\right)\ ?.
$$

See equation (6.3) in Espinosa's https://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1015706300169

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin(\pi x)\ln(\sin(\pi x))dx=F(x)\big|_0^1,$$ where $F'(x)=\sin(\pi x)\ln(\sin(\pi x)),x\in(0,1)$ .

It's common for the partial integrations that they introduce spurious singularities if the two factors in the kernel
are split such that they are not individually finite. In the case here the logarithm has a pole (or singularity) and the
sine dampens this such that the integral is finite. But as one factor (the sine) is integrated, it's no longer capable
of confining the singularity of the other factor (the logarithm), and the prefactor is infinite at one limit. The partial
integration still works if one introduces the limits after the full evaluation such that these singularities cancel.

Noticing that
$$
I \stackrel{x\mapsto 1- x}{=}  \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \ln (\Gamma(x)) d x
,$$
averaging them and using the reflection property of Gamma function yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \ln (\Gamma(1-x) \Gamma(\pi)) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) \ln (\pi \csc (\pi x)) d x\\& =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi \sin (x) \ln (\pi \csc (x)) d x \quad  (\textrm{ Via }\pi x\mapsto x) \\&= \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^\pi \sin x \ln (\sin x) d x\\& =\frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}-\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{-1}^1 \ln \left(1-c^2\right) d c \text {, where } c=\cos x \\ &= \frac{\ln \pi}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2 \pi}(2 \ln 2-2)\\&= \frac{1}{\pi } \ln \left(\frac{\pi e}{2 }\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $u=\cos x$, then $\sin^2x=1-u^2$, and we can get:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{-1}^1\log\left(1-u^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac12\left[\int_{-1}^1\log(1-u)\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_{-1}^1\log(1+u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right]\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\log(1+u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^2\log(v)\,\mathrm{d}v\\
&=[v\log(v)-v]\bigg|_0^2\\
&=2\log(2)-2.
\end{align}$$
So your integral is
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin(\pi x)\ln(\sin(\pi x))dx=
\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\log(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{2\log(2)-2}{\pi}.$$

To simplify the notation substitute $1-x = q$
$$
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x) \ln \Gamma(1-x) dx
= 
-\int_1^0 \sin(\pi (1-q)) \ln \Gamma q dq
= 
$$
$$
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi (1-q)) \ln \Gamma q dq
= 
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi q) \ln \Gamma q dq.
$$
The Fourier series  is (see the wikipedia article about the $\Gamma$-function)
$$
\log \Gamma z = (\frac12-z)(\gamma+\log 2)+(1-z)\log \pi -1/2\log \sin(\pi z)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\log n}{n} \sin(2\pi nz).
$$
$$
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi q) \ln \Gamma q dq
= 
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi q)[(\frac12-q)(\gamma+\log 2)+(1-q)\log \pi -1/2\log \sin(\pi q)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\log n}{n} \sin(2\pi nq]dq
$$
$$
= 
\int_0^1 \sin(\pi q)[(1-q)\log \pi -1/2\log \sin(\pi q)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\log n}{n} \sin(2\pi nq)]dq
$$
$$
=
\frac{\log \pi}{\pi}+ \int_0^1 \sin(\pi q)[-1/2\log \sin(\pi q)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\log n}{n} \sin(2\pi nq)]dq
$$
$$
= 
\frac{\log \pi}{\pi}-\frac{\log 2 -1}{\pi} +\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n\ge 1}\int_0^1 \sin(\pi q)\frac{\log n}{n} \sin(2\pi nq) dq
$$
$$
= 
\frac{\log \pi}{\pi}-\frac{\log 2 -1}{\pi}
\approx 0.46205312
$$
as in A375366.
